# Counting database applications

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can we find out that how many applications are there in a database?

Comment: your question makes no sense.

Comment: I think he's asking how many connections open to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking for here. I'm assuming you mean "Applications written using SQL Server 2005 as the database.".

If that's what you want to know, I don't know of any single place you could get that information by it's always a good idea to try starting [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean stored procedures? You can have multiple applications using the same login credentials accessing a given database from the same web server, so you can't simply count databases or tables to get that number.